# Tabs break when browser resized

Tags: html, css

I have setup the following JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzvGz/

CSS:

```
ul#tabs
{
    width: 712px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul#tabs > li:first-child
{
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
ul#tabs > li
{
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    border: 1px solid #AAB7D5;
}

ul#tabs > li > a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: 0;
    color: #515151;
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 88%;
}

ul#tabs > #tab0
{
    width: 166px;
}

ul#tabs > #tab1
{
    width: 227px;
}
ul#tabs > #tab2
{
    width: 130px;
}
ul#tabs > #tab3
{
    width: 157px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li id="tab0"><a href="#">TEST TAB #1</a></li>
        <li id="tab1"><a href="#">TEST TAB #2</a></li>
        <li id="tab2"><a href="#">TEST TAB #2</a></li>
        <li id="tab3"><a href="#">TEST TAB #4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the browser is resized (ctrl + plus), it breaks the tabs into a new line. How do I keep it all in one line?

Comment: I think when you resize (ctrl+plus), you should refresh the page (f5), did you try that ?

Comment: Try using %ages instead of fixed widths

Comment: Im not seeing the breaking you're describing.  can you take a screenshot? or do you mean the text is broken up onto a second line?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have made the text a little to big for your container.

Try changing this setting, from:

```
ul#tabs > li > a
{
 padding-left: 45px;
}
```

to this:

```
ul#tabs > li > a
{
 padding-left: 40px;
}
```

so the text would fit.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about the text breaking up into two lines, change

```
ul#tabs > li > a
{
  ...
  padding-left: 45px;
  ...
}
```

to

```
    text-align:center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzvGz/1/